# Adding new button and spinner for each button click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

In the activity when user click on add client button I want to add new view to the screen which contains a spinner with list of client names retrieved from api and a button that will do some action on click.

So I thought I would use a recycleview and adapter for this but I think I'm wrong

in the activity I have the adapter

```
private ClientAdapter clientAdapter;
```

When I retrieve clients name from API I set the adapter as

```
   clientRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
   clientAdapter= new clientAdapter(clientList , this , this);
   clientRecyclerView.setAdapter(podAdapter);
```

At this point I don't want the recycle view to render anything until user click on add new client button then I want to display one item that has spinner with client names and a button.
Then if he clicks again on add client button I want to show another spinner and button and so on.

However now I'm having 3 clients so recycleview render 3 view items which make sense.
But what the trick that I should do to achieve my goal?

[image]

Here's my adapter

```
public class ClintsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClintsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Clients> clientsList;
    private EventListener listener;


    public ClintsAdapter(List<Clients> clientsList, EventListener listener , Context context) {
        this.clientsList = clientsList;
        this.EventListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override // To inflate view
    public ClintsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem_client, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view, listener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClintsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ClintsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Client>(context, R.layout.spinner_text_view, clientsList);
        ClintsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.clientSpinner.setAdapter(ClintsAdapter);
        holder.clientSpinner.setTitle("Choose client");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (clientsList == null)
            return 0;
        return clientsList.size();
    }

    public interface PODListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private SearchableSpinner clientSpinner , collectMethodSpinner;

        EventListener listener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, final EventListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listener = podListener;
            clientSpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_client);
            btnComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_comment);

            btnComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if ( listener != null ) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onClick(position);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my list item

Comment: I suggest that you open MS Paint or a similar program and draw what you want each screen to look like. You can post these drawing here and it will help us better understand the words you use to describe it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Okay I agree the question is not very clear , I will add photo

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Added :) Thank you

Comment: RecyclerView is definitely the right tool to do what you want. What problem did you encounter when you tried to implement it? Will you show the code for `ClientAdapter` and the layout it uses for each row?

Comment: Can you explain why you required a button and Spinner in it cause you required to do some extra configuration for that which will store the values of items. and you said you have 3 customer so each ViewHolder can have unique item in spinner or can be different also

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The problem is I'm passing list of clients to the adapter (size of 3) then the adapter render 3 items. I don't want this behavior I want to have 0 item if user click on add I will render one item and so on .. I hope it's clear

Comment: @Bhavin This is the scenario, User will click on add client button so i will render one item view with spinner having clients name from our db so user will choose from then he can press on button to add extra information about this specific client he selected

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added the adapter code

Comment: I deleted my answer since I misunderstood some details of what you are doing. The ArrayAdapter I looked at is the one for the spinner, not for the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> The problem is I'm passing list of clients to the adapter (size of 3) then the adapter render 3 items. I don't want this behavior I want to have 0 item if user click on add I will render one item and so on

You are using a single `ArrayList<Client>` for two different purposes:

1. The list of clients to choose from in the spinner
2. The number of spinners to display in the RecyclerView.

These are two separate things, so you need two separate lists.

Comment: My adapter is already extending RecyclerView.Adapter.I didn't get what you mean by client data. What I need is on user clicks "Add client" I always want to show a spinner with clients name and a button x. when button x clicked i want to show edit text.

Comment: @R_1996 ok, ignore my comment about "client data" then.

Comment: @R_1996 Sorry for the confusion. I didn't look close enough at your code and made some assumptions. Hopefully the edited answer is more helpful than my previous version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with just adding `integer` value for your `ClientsAdapter`. Set its default value as 0 and create a method for changing it's value. When you want to add new item (new `Spinner` and `Button`) use that method and notify your adapter.

Add a new field called `count` for your `ClientsAdapter`.

```
private int count;
```

Inside constructor assign its value to 0. So on start its value will be 0 and `RecyclerView` will show nothing.

```
public ClintsAdapter(List<Clients> clientsList, EventListener listener , Context context){
    this.clientsList = clientsList;
    this.EventListener = listener;
    count = 0;
}
```

Change `getItemCount` method's `return` value. According to your code `getItemCount` returns size of your `List`. That `List` is for `Spinner` and has no relation with this method. Instead of returning your `List`'s size return `count`.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return count;
}
```

Create a method for changing `count`'s value. `count` starts with 0 (assigned it 0 inside constructor) and when you click `Button` (add new `Spinner` and `Button`) this method will change its value.

```
public void addItem(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
```

Whenever you click `Button` simply call `addItem` method and pass new `count` value and notify your `clientAdapter`.

```
addClient.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    int count = clientRecyclerView.getChildCount();
    clientAdapter.addItem(count+1);
    clientAdapter.notifyItemInserted(count);
});
```

**NOTE:** I don't get it why you're setting `podAdapter` for `RecyclerView`.

```
clientRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
clientAdapter= new clientAdapter(clientList , this , this);
clientRecyclerView.setAdapter(podAdapter);
```

You're creating `clientAdapter` reference for your `ClientsAdapter` but while setting adapter for `RecyclerView`, you're using different reference (`podAdapter`).

Full code for  `ClientsAdapter`:

```
public class ClintsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClintsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Clients> clientsList;
    private EventListener listener;
    private int count;


    public ClintsAdapter(List<Clients> clientsList, EventListener listener , Context context) {
        this.clientsList = clientsList;
        this.EventListener = listener;
        count = 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override // To inflate view
    public ClintsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem_client, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view, listener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ClintsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ClintsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Client>(context, R.layout.spinner_text_view, clientsList);
        ClintsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.clientSpinner.setAdapter(ClintsAdapter);
        holder.clientSpinner.setTitle("Choose client");
    }

    public void addItem(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }    

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public interface PODListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private SearchableSpinner clientSpinner , collectMethodSpinner;

        EventListener listener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, final EventListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listener = podListener;
            clientSpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_client);
            btnComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_comment);

            btnComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if ( listener != null ) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onClick(position);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
}
```